# Set PXGridColumn as readonly

Tags: acumatica

I have a formtab screen that I would like the grids in the tabs to be readonly.  I have already set the skinid to Inquire which removes the add and delete, but I wanted to disallow clicking inside the columns to change the data.  It cannot be saved as the form portion has all fields disabled.  This is primarily for viewing the data and there is one action button to close the item.  I just want to eliminate any confusion for the users by disallowing changes to the column data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thing maybe worked in your case.
You can set all your field attribute Enable = false in design, follow this:

> add this code to your design
>
> `<Mode AllowAddNew="false" AllowDelete="false" AllowUpdate="false" />`

```
<px:PXGridLevel DataMember="">
   <Columns>
        // Grid Column
   </Columns>
   
   // Code enable in design
   <Mode AllowAddNew="false" AllowDelete="false" AllowUpdate="false" />

   <RowTemplate>
       // Controls for columns              
   </RowTemplate>
</px:PXGridLevel>
```

Or in BLC with code below

> In RowSelected Event of PrimaryView:

```
// Disable Edit Data In Grid 
GridDataView.AllowInsert = false;
GridDataView.AllowDelete = false;
GridDataView.AllowUpdate = false;

// Disable Field
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<GridDataView.Field>(cache, row, false);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I did set all the fields in the form area to enabled=false in the designer, but I could not find that option for the gridcolumns. I searched for readonly or enabled options in the designer but I did not see either.

Comment: without having to disable all fields individially you would use the disable edit data in grid option in the answer. Use your data view name .AllowUpdate = false for example. If you need selective rows then you would use SenEnabled and use call without field name to disable some rows and not others.

Comment: If you can't disable in design you should use your `PrimaryView` in your BLC  and set Property same with my code. It takes much time with design page but it easily and maybe it will help you in the future.

Comment: You can use Designer tool to set enabled, follow this: below <Columns> add <Mode AllowAddNew="false" AllowDelete="false" AllowUpdate="false" />.
In there, <Mode/> is same level with <Columns>